# Enable to load image

Tags: php, html, image, codeigniter

I use codeigniter framework for develop my database but there is minor problem in this database that is image

**image show like this:**

[image]

but when i make right click on it and click on open image in new tab it show this error

**Error of image open in new tab:**

[image]

and also if i refresh the url again after error message,now image open and also the main page where i start this also image open.
Can anyone please tell me what is the problem,is this hosting problem or coding problem.
i'm using this code for place image

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 marg" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <?php
            if(count($siteinfos->photo)) {
                echo "<center>";
                echo "<img width='50' height='50' src=".base_url('uploads/images/'.$siteinfos->photo)." />";
                echo "</center>";
            }
        ?>
        <center><h4><?php echo $siteinfos->sname; ?></h4></center>
</div>
```

Comment: is the URL correct??

Comment: The image location is not correct. Make sure you're using the correct path for the image.

Comment: agree.. image location incorrect. Place your code you're using to show the image.

Comment: Please check the url http://webconsociates.com/

Comment: Checking your URL is not going to change for anyone that the path to the image is not correct.

Comment: the console state tht the image is not find, fix ur path

Comment: Please check the url http://webconsociates.com/ and open the image right clicking in the new tab you will see error but when you reload the url image will be accessable. Which shows image url is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First load `url` helper in controller from where data is passed to the view.Like this...

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then only you can use `base_url()`.Replace your above code with following..

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 marg" style="margin-top:30px;">
<?php
    if(count($siteinfos->photo)) { ?>
       <center><img width='50' height='50' src=" <?php echo base_url('uploads/images/').$siteinfos->photo;?>" /></center>
 <?php    }
?>
<center><h4><?php echo $siteinfos->sname; ?></h4></center>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for response but i have placed this code on my database, same problem also now image not shown after right click .